# Array of buttons, textboxes and labels with their properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to store in the same array - list of different type elements declaring in the same array different property value (bool)? For exampe list of those elements:

```
GV1_BTNEdit.Visible = false;
GV1_BTNCancel.Visible = true;

GV1.Columns[3].Visible = true;
GV1.Columns[5].Visible = true;
GV1.Columns[4].Visible = true;

Lbl1_GV1.Visible = true;
```

**Edit: (pseudo-code)**
**This is how funcionality should look like:**

Declares a list/array of elements with a simultaneous declaration of parameters / properties of these elements:

```
list/element array (list_name)
{
textbox1.visible = true;
label1.visible = false;
button1.visible = true;
}
```

Calling a list/array, i.e. simultaneous assignment to the elements of the list - the property resulting from their declaration in the list:

```
list_name[];
```

Calling the list with the same property change, i.e. simultaneous assigning to all elements of the list the property visible = false:

```
list_name[i].visible = false;
```

Calling the list with changing the property of visible elements to the opposite (i.e. what was true will change to false, and what was false - to true):

```
list_name[i].visible != list_name[i].visible;
```

If, after all, it cannot be done in this particular way, is there another similar possibility?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, often it is better to place a group of controls say inside of  div, and then simple hide/show the div to show/hide the group of controls.

so say this:

```
<div id="BillAddress" runat="sever">
    Text address, and more controls here
</div>
```

Then in code, you can hide/show the whole mess with

```
 BillAddress.Style("display") = "none";
```

Or to show that group of controls, then this:

```
 BillAddress.Style("display") = "normal";
```

So, web land, and web markup lends itself to MUCH better using span's, or div's, or whatever to group controls.

And the beauty of above, is then you can also often wirte client side code in JavaScript to hide/show groups of controls inside that div 100% with client side code.

Having stated + suggested the above?

You can also say cook up your "own" attributes on a group of controls.

Say:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
             MyGroup="Billing" >
        </asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCity" runat="server"
             MyGroup="Billing>
        </asp:TextBox>
```

So, note how in above I just made up a attribute for the control.

Then, in code,  can do this:

```
    For Each c As System.Web.UI.Control In Page.Controls
     If c.Attributes("MyBilling") IsNot Nothing Then

           // hide/show the control
```

So, in web land, I don't really think it makes a whole lot of sense to attempt to group some controls in a array - just drop all those controls inside of some div, and hide/show that div. But, you can use "tag" or even cook up + add your own attributes to controls, and then loop the controls in that page, or div or whatever.

For example, I cooked up my own "data binder" routine.

I simple will place a group of controls say inside of a "div" with a "id" and runat server.

Then, to load data into that "div" and set of controls?

I place controls in a div, and then I can do this:

```
  int intPK = (int)ViewState[this.ID + "_MyPk"];
  string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + this.MyTable + " WHERE ID = " + intPK;
  DataTable rstData = General.MyRst(strSQL);
  General.FLoader(this.EditRecord, rstData.Rows[0]);
```

In above, EditRecord is my "div"

The markup looks like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HotelName" width="280"></asp:TextBox> <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
```

etc. etc.

So, I use a made up attribute called "f", where f="database column name"

So, with that simple idea, then I can load up a whole data form with about 3 lines of code.

So, say I click edit on a grid.

I pop this form:

[image]

but, the form data is done with my fLoader routine. All it does is look for "f" attributes, and fills out the control from the database.

And then for save, I have Fwriter. Does the same thing, but in reverse.

So, save button code for above is this:

```
    protected void cmdSave_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intPK = (int)ViewState[this.ID + "_MyPk"];
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = " + intPK;
        DataTable rstData = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        General.FWriterUpdate(this.EditRecord, rstData.Rows[0]);
    }
```

So, Fwriter again just loops the controls inside of that div, and transfers back from the controls their values into the table.

So, in above, we see two examples of grouping controls, and then being able to "operate" on that group of controls.

No arrays required here. so, I used these concepts for my own data binding system, and thus I NEVER have to write code to load up each individual control from the database. Nor do I have to write code to send + save the data back to the database.

I means I quite much have ms-access like drag + drop of controls, and the shuffle from database to the form is done for me. And this all works due to the requiring to "group" and identify controls on the page, and what I want to do with that group of controls.

## Edit: Processing conrols in an array or list

In all of the above "div" and control processing routines, we REALLY are doing the same as if we placed the controls into an array, or list.

For example, the floader routine does this: (we can pass it the current web page, or as more often a "div".

So, it looks like this:

```
            foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in F.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    TextBox ctlC = c as TextBox;
                    ctlC.Text = "zoo";
                    ctlC.Visible = true;

                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    Label ctlC = c as Label;

                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
                {
                    DropDownList ctlC = c as DropDownList;
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    CheckBox ctlC = c as CheckBox;

                }
```

I removed most of the code, but above shows how you can pass/have a bunch of controls in a page, or div or whatever.

So, my WHOLE post and narrative been based on the above approach - which I assumed was obvious here.

However, lets code up a collection, and thus make this even more obvious.

so this markup:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
```

So, our code behind can then do this:

```
        List<Control> mycontrols = new List<Control>();
        mycontrols.Add(TextBox1);
        mycontrols.Add(CheckBox2);
        mycontrols.Add(Label1);

        foreach (Control myC in mycontrols)
        {
            myC.Visible = false;


        }
        // set text value of controls
        foreach (Control myC in mycontrols)
        {
            myC.Visible = false;
            if (myC.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                TextBox ctlC = myC as TextBox;
                ctlC.Text = "zoo";
                ctlC.Visible = true;

            }
            else if (myC.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                Label ctlC = c as Label;
                ctlC.Text = "zoo zoo";

            }
            else if (myC.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                CheckBox ctlC = c as CheckBox;
                ctlC.Checked = true;

            }
        }
```

So, for visible, we can use visible property. but, for other features of the control, say like Text or whatever? We cast the control into its type, and thus can use say checked of the checkbox, and it does not even have a .text property.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I also had a similar idea ... except that instead of div - I used tables. However, I would like to note that if there were more controls, the code of additional divs / tables would grow a lot and therefore creating some kind of - parameterized elements list/arrays could be (sometimes) more interesting (if possible at all), because it would allow you to quickly change the parameters of many elements (in this list/array) that would have the same effect as hiding the div, and also - if it were not the visible parameter (and some other parameter) it would give even more options.

Comment: Well, you could/can pass a list of controls to some routine, but the real issue is how was the list to be created in the first place? As my data loader example shows, I pass the div with the control(s) in side and then the code operates on all of the controls inside of that div to load up data. Those controls can be text box, labels, drop down, check box etc. As the screen shot shows, there was/is quite a variation of the controls.  So, you have and can create some array (or collection/list) of controls - it how you going to figure out what control belongs in that list that is the work.

Comment: What about... Control[] list=new Control[] { textbox1,label1,button1 }; Problem is that I do not know how to declare "visible" parameters (deifferent for each element) in the same time.

Comment: I been assuming all along that you can have a list in a array, or list, and then process that list. I mean, how do you think I am able to process controls in a div? So yes, see my edit and addition to the above post. I much assumed that you can have a list or collection of controls, but the real issue is how you group those controls. That's why I suggested passing a "div" or even having a custom attribute for this purpose. But to be clear? yes, you can add/have controls in a list, and process them - see the example code and part 2 of above post for example code.

Comment: foreach(Control contr in list) contr.Visible=true; foreach(Control contr in list) contr.Visible=false; foreach(Control contr in list) contr.Visible=!contr.Visible; Yes, I know but still I do not know how to declare element property in same list (or in same list have some kind pointing on specific elements propertys values) ... and just only after that changing elements propertys will have any sense

Comment: You as my follow up code need to cast the "control" to the given type to get at the controls. (I think that what you asking about). So, yes, if you have a array (or list) of controls, and want to operate on say text or other properties of that control? Yes, you do have to test/check the control type, and then cast as per my above control. this still means you have a foreach, and can't say operate on that group of controls like you could with a VB6 control array. However, a few helper functions, and you achieve quite much the same thing. I might be miss-understanding your question here?

Comment: so, as far as I know, that list or array? Yes, you need to cast to the correct control type to change or access/get use of those extra properties.